# Получить из списка неповторяющиеся элементы

Tags: c#, plinq

Есть список из 7 000 000 строк. В нем хранятся названия книг и их авторы.

Как средствами PLINQ, в один запрос желательно, получить неповторяющиеся фамилии авторов?

p.s. разделители (отделяют книгу от фамилии в строке) могут быть любыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<string>
            {
                "Book 1, Author 1",
                "Book 2 | Author 2",
                "Book3 > Author 1",
                "Book 4 : Author 2"
            };

            var result = list.AsParallel().Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=[,|>:]).+").Value).Distinct();
            result.ForAll(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:
на основе строк сформировать некое множество

```
var books= new list<book>
```

и работать с ним так:

```
  var authors= from c in books
                        select c.authorName;
    var distinctAuthors = authors.Distinct();
```

или одним запросом :

```
var Disauthors= (from c in books
                            select c.authorName).Distinct();
```